# Django With Clean Architecture

Tags: python, django, architecture, clean-architecture

I'm trying to build a python application using Clean Architecture principles. I already have the following structure:

```
app/
├── src
│   ├── dependencies
│   │   ├── dependencies.py
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── infrastructure
│   │   └── ui
│   │       ├── __init__.py
│   │       ├── interfaces
│   │       │   ├── __init__.py
│   │       │   └── ui.py
│   │       ├── desktop
│   │       │   ├── __init__.py
│   │       │   └── tkinter_ui.py
│   │       └── web
│   │           ├── flask_ui
│   │           │   ├── constants
│   │           │   │   ├── constants.py
│   │           │   │   └── __init__.py
│   │           │   ├── endpoints
│   │           │   │   ├── endpoints.py
│   │           │   │   └── __init__.py
│   │           │   ├── flask_ui.py
│   │           │   └── __init__.py
│   │           └── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── main.py
Makefile
```

And it works fine for both Tkinter and Flask. Now I'm considering adding django to my project, so I thought my structure would be something like this:

```
app/
├── src
│   ├── dependencies
│   │   ├── dependencies.py
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── infrastructure
│   │   └── ui
│   │       ├── __init__.py
│   │       ├── interfaces
│   │       │   ├── __init__.py
│   │       │   └── ui.py
│   │       ├── desktop
│   │       │   ├── __init__.py
│   │       │   └── tkinter_ui.py
│   │       └── web
│   │           ├── django_ui
│   │           │   ├── constants
│   │           │   │   ├── constants.py
│   │           │   │   └── __init__.py
│   │           │   ├── django_webserver
│   │           │   │   ├── db.sqlite3
│   │           │   │   ├── django_webserver
│   │           │   │   │   ├── asgi.py
│   │           │   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │           │   │   │   ├── settings.py
│   │           │   │   │   ├── urls.py
│   │           │   │   │   └── wsgi.py
│   │           │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │           │   │   └── manage.py
│   │           │   ├── __init__.py
│   │           │   └── django_ui.py
│   │           ├── flask_ui
│   │           │   ├── constants
│   │           │   │   ├── constants.py
│   │           │   │   └── __init__.py
│   │           │   ├── endpoints
│   │           │   │   ├── endpoints.py
│   │           │   │   └── __init__.py
│   │           │   ├── flask_ui.py
│   │           │   └── __init__.py
│   │           └── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── main.py
Makefile
```

But I'm facing several errors while trying to run django from the same way I'm running flask/tkinter.

Here's some of my code to help understanding how it works:

```
Makefile

run:
    cd app/src && python -m main
```

```py
main.py

from dependencies import ui_factory


def main() -> None:
    ui = ui_factory()
    ui.execute()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

```py
dependencies.py
from infrastructure.ui.interfaces import UI


def ui_factory() -> UI:
    """
    This is how I'm hoping to retrieve the django ui so I can run it on main.py

    from infrastructure.ui.web.django_ui.django_webserver.django_ui import DjangoUI
    return DjangoUI()
    """

    from infrastructure.ui.web.flask_ui import FlaskUI
    return FlaskUI()
```

```py
flask_ui.py

from flask import Flask

from .constants import FLASK_SECRET_KEY
from .endpoints import endpoints
from ...interfaces import UI


class FlaskUI(UI):
    _flask: Flask

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self._flask = Flask(__name__)

    def execute(self) -> None:
        self._configure()
        self._create_routes()

        self._flask.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5_000)
```

I already tried to create my `django_ui.py` module like so:

```py
django_ui.py

import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from django.core.management import call_command


class DjangoUI(UI):
    def execute(self) -> None:
        os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "django_webserver.settings")
        application = get_wsgi_application()
        call_command('runserver',  '127.0.0.1:8000')
```

and also using `execute_from_command_line(...)` function but nothing seems to work. I think I can create a dockerfile to start the django server (by using `python manage.py runserver` directly or something like that but I haven't tried this solution yet since this is different from what I want - to be able to return the DjangoUI class to be executed on main.py.

Is that something possible to achieve? Or should I be doing something different?
Any feedbacks and insights are very much appreciated.

---

Some of the errors are listed below:

When using:

```py
def execute(self) -> None:
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "infrastructure.ui.web.django_ui.django_webserver.django_webserver.settings")
        application = get_wsgi_application()
        call_command('runserver')
```

I'm getting:
`raise ImproperlyConfigured( django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: WSGI application 'django_webserver.wsgi.application' could not be loaded; Error importing module.`

When using:

```py
def execute(self) -> None:
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "django_webserver.settings")
        application = get_wsgi_application()
        call_command('runserver')
```

I'm getting:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_webserver'`

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: @ewokx added some error examples.

Comment: Did you install django-webserver?

Comment: @ewokx `django-webserver` is just the name I gave for `myapp`. I can rename it to anything else, like `myapp`, `django_ui`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

So I manage to fix it by replacing all `django_webserver.settings` references to use the whole path instead (`infrastructure.ui.web.django_ui.django_webserver.django_webserver.settings`)

That fixed the issue.